# Conver CFStringRef to C counterpart?

Tags: objective-c, c, linux

I am converting an objective-c program to a C program in linux. I have most of it covered, but I cannot find the C counterpart for `CFStringRef`.

I would guess that its counterpart is `char` but I am not sure.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `CFStringRef` is a string, in C, `char*` is a string.

Comment: @Linuxios So they are basically the same thing?

Comment: If you can work in C++, you may find that it is a bit easier to convert CFStringRef code to std::string than to char* if the string manipulation is non-trivial. You don't need extensive C++ knowledge to do that, particularly if you're not too worried about copying the strings a little more than is necessary. Most C code is perfectly fine C++. You can just use std::string when it's convenient. NSArray also usually translates more easily to std::vector than to C-arrays.

Comment: @RobNapier Could you please give me an example? I am new to C, so this is a big challenge understanding everything.

Comment: Of course, you can also skip some of the translation by just using GNUStep. GNUStep is basically Foundation (NSWhatever) and CoreFoundation (CFWhatever) for Linux.

Comment: @Linuxios Thank you for mentioning that! I'll look into it.

Comment: If you were converting `CFStringCreateCopy()` to use `char*`, you need to `malloc` memory for the new pointer, then use `strncpy` to copy the data over, and then when you're done with the string, you need to call `free()` on it. If you wanted to convert it to `std::string`, you'd say `string b = a` and you're done. That said, there really is no shortcut to learning C or C++. You need to spend a little time with lessons and tutorials or you're likely to have a lot of memory problems.

Comment: @RobNapier Ok. I think before I do anything bigger I need to sit down and properly learn C. Thank you!

Comment: @Linuxios Makes a great point. Since you're just using CoreFoundation, it's actually even easier than that. Much of CoreFoundation is opensource and builds on Linux. http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.17/ (Builds on Linux as I recall… it's been a long time since I've tried it.)

Comment: @RobNapier It is open source? Oops, I did not know that...

Comment: @RobNapier: I didn't realize that CoreFoundation itself was open source. That's probably even better than using GNUStep.

Comment: @RobNapier could you add that as an answer? If it works, I can probably accept it tomorrow.

Comment: In case you were wondering; it's completely possible to set up a modern Objective-C 2.0 build chain in Linux.  I've just achieved this for myself, even including GCD, blocks support and the Foundation package courtesy of GNUstep.

To make this productive I feel a modern IDE with Objective-C support in Linux is required.  Perhaps the answer could come from here?

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3353

I'd encourage you to sign-in and vote for this issue if it's of interest.

Comment: @ChrisHatton how did you set yours up? I had trouble building CF and CFLite, and eventually gave up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, CoreFoundation is open source. It is easier to compile it and use the built in functions then to find their C counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

`CFStringRef` is a string, and in C, strings are `char*`s.

They both, at some high level of abstraction, are strings. However, you aren't going to find C equivalents to many Objective-C constructs because Objective-C is simply a higher level language. CFStringRef is essentially a pointer to an "object" that can do nearly everything that NSString can. char* is an array of characters that can be manipulated by a few builtin functions and that requires manual memory management. You'll find that many things that you could do with one function call using `CFStringRef` will require quite a few lines in C just to do the memory management.